# Akka IO app consumes 100% cpu

Tags: scala, akka, profiling, visualvm

I am trying to profile an Akka app that is constantly at or near 100% CPU usage. I took a CPU sample using `visualvm`. The sample indicates that there are 2 threads that make up 98.9% of CPU usage. 79% of the cpu time was spent on a method called `sun.misc.Unsafe`. [Other answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241335/waiting-at-sun-misc-unsafe-parknative-method) say that it just means that a thread is waiting but in the native implementation layer (outside of the jvm).

In questions similar to mine, people have been [told to look elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673523/akka-threads-use-100-cpu-while-application-is-idle) without being given specifics. Where should I look to figure out what's causing the cpu spike?

The application is a server that primarily uses Akka IO to listen for TCP socket connections.

Comment: You say you took a CPU sample. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: sun.misc.Unsafe is not a method, it is a Class. Please show the full stack trace.

Comment: I have a similar issue when I try to use Spring Rest Template client in the actor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49301174/resttemplate-uses-100-cpu-of-remote-url-is-not-available-when-i-use-httpcompone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing any of the source code, or even knowing what IO channel you are talking about (sockets, files, etc), there is very little insight that anyone here can give you.

I do have some rather general suggestions though.

First, **you should be using reactive techniques and reactive IO in your application.** This issue could be occurring because you are polling the status of some resource in a tight loop, or using a blocking call when you should be using a reactive one. This tends to be an anti-pattern and a performance drain exactly because you can spend CPU cycles doing nothing but "actively waiting". I recommend double checking for:

- resource polling
- blocking calls

  - system calls
  - disk flushes
  - waiting on a `Future` when it would be appropriate to `map` it instead

Second, **you should NOT be using Mutexes or other thread synchronization in your application.** If so, then you might be suffering from a live-lock. Unlike dead-locks, live-locks manifest with symptoms like 100% CPU usage as threads constantly lock and unlock concurrency primitives in an attempt to "catch them all". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Livelock) has a nice technical description of what a live lock looks like. With Akka in place you shouldn't have any need to use Mutexes or any thread synchronization primitives. If you are then you probably need to re-design your application.

Third, **you should be throttling IO (as well as error handling like reconnection attempts).** This issue could be occurring because your system lacks effective throttling. Often with data channels we leave their bandwidth unconstrained. However this can become an issue when that channel reaches 100% saturation and begins to steal resources from other parts of the system. This can happen, for example, if you are moving large files around without a reasonable limit.

Alternatively, you also need to throttle connection retries when you encounter any errors, rather than retrying immediately. Lots of systems will attempt to reconnect to a server if they lose their connection. While normally desirable, this can lead to problematic behavior if you use a naive reconnection strategy. For example, imagine a network client that was written this way:

```
class MyClient extends Client {
... other code...
  def onDisconnect() = {
    reconnect()
  }
}
```

Every time the Client disconnects for ANY reason it will attempt to reconnect. You can see how this would cause a tight loop between the error handling code and the Client if the Wifi cut-out or a network cable was unplugged.

Fourth, **your application should have well defined data sources and sinks.** Your issue could be caused by a "data loop", that is some set of Akka actors that are just sending messages to the next actor in the chain, with the last actor sending the message back to the first actor in the chain. Make sure you have a clear and definite way for messages to enter and exit your system.

Fifth, **use appropriate profiling and instrumentation for your application.** Instrument your application using [Kamon](http://kamon.io/) or Coda Hale's Metrics library.

Finding an appropriate profiler will be more difficult, since we as a community have far to go to develop mature tools for reactive applications. Personally I have found `visualvm` useful, but not always overwhelmingly helpful for detecting code paths that are CPU bound. The issue is that sampling profilers are only able to collect data when the JVM reaches a safepoint. This has the potential to bias certain code paths. The fix is to use a profiler that supports `AsyncGetStackTrace`.

Best of luck! And please add more context if you can.